# How to bind nested model in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding

I am using asp.net and razor.
I have a viewmodel and a view. The viewmodel has a nested model property.

```
    public class A {

       Prop 1 {get;set;}
       Prop 2 {get;set;}
       B NestedClass {get;set}

   }

    public class B {

        Prop 1 {get;set;}
        Prop 2 {get;set;}

    }
```

I don't want to render a (partial) view for the `B` intially but only for some properties of `A` and load a view for `B` using `ajax` at some point.

The partial view is bound to B:

```
@model B
```

Per design I want to store all information in one model class.
How do I bind the partial views fields to `A` in order to perform a `submit`?
Somehow I have to make clear, that I am using `B` as nested Model in `A`?

Update:
Updated code snippet for better understanding / contained a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As model binding is working using naming convetions a solution using `Html.Helpers` would be to explicitly set the `Name` attribute:

```
public Class B{

        Prop 1 {get;set;}
        Prop 2 {get;set;}

    }
```

**Partial View** for `B` would be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1, new { i, name="NestedClass.Prop1" })
```