# How can I bind form fields to a nested model on post?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, post, model-binding, mediatr

I am coding a solution where the user will submit a form, posting the values back to my ASP.NET MVC controller.  My model is complex and the form fields are contained in a nested object (I'm using CQRS via MediatR).  When I submit the form, the values come across as null.  How can I get the complex model to recognize the form fields?

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("edit")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UpdateApplicationCommand command)
        {
            await _mediator.Send(command)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Models:

```
    public class UpdateApplicationCommand : IRequest<Unit>
    {
        public ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

```
    public class ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

View:

```
    @model ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel

        <form method="post" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Applications">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Application Name"})
                <label for="Name">Application Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Application Description"})
                <label for="Description">Application Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

I've tried to reduce the complex model to its fields, by placing the contents of the `ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel` directly into the `UpdateApplicationCommand` class.  This worked, but I'd really like to keep the nested structure so that I can reuse the `ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel` object.

I saw this solution here:

- [How to bind nested model in partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889033/how-to-bind-nested-model-in-partial-view)

But I'd rather avoid adding the name as a route object (if possible) for every form field.  Is there another, more simple way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way, you can custom model binding like below:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        var model = new UpdateApplicationCommand()
        {
            ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel = new ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel()
            {
                Description = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Description").ToString(),
                Name = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Name").ToString()
            }
        };
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Apply the custom model binding like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]UpdateApplicationCommand model)
{
    //.....
}
```

---

The second way, just change your razor view like below:

```
@model UpdateApplicationCommand

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Application Name"})
        <label for="Name">Application Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationEditGeneralViewModel.Description, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Application Description"})
        <label for="Description">Application Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" />
    </div>
</form>
```